# AXIS2 habdler exceptiob

Tags: apache, apache-axis

i create axis2 handler "SimpleHandler" , and register it in OutFlow using:

```
 <phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
    <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
<phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
    <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
    <!--system predefined phase-->
    <!--these phase will run irrespective of the service-->
    <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
    <phase name="MessageOut" >
             <handler name="digitalSign2"              class="com.asset.vsv.adapters.hlr.integration.SimpleHandler" > <order phase="PreDispatch"/>
            </handler>  
    </phase>
    <phase name="Security"/>
</phaseOrder>
```

but this exception throws

```
2013-12-22 16:39:22 ERROR ClientUtils:80 - The system cannot infer the transport information from the http://qq.qq.qq.qq:8084/hlr-sim/SPMLHlrSubscriber45Service URL.
```

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the http://qq.q.qq.qq:8084/hlr-sim/SPMLHlrSubscriber45Service URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:304)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at wsdl._5._4.hlr_subscriber.gw.prov.names.siemens.SPMLHlrSubscriber45ServiceStub.modify(SPMLHlrSubscriber45ServiceStub.java:806)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

There is no PreDispatch or Dispatch phase in OutFlow, since this is the response path. So you hanlder should be as below.

```
<phase name="MessageOut" >
             <handler name="digitalSign2"              class="com.asset.vsv.adapters.hlr.integration.SimpleHandler" > <order phase="MessageOut"/>
            </handler>
```